# AD migration 2008 r2 to 2012 r2 - must've missed something

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, migration

I finally went through with this the other day.  Got DNS/AD setup, seized FSMO roles on the 2012 server, migrated DHCP etc.  I thought I was ready to go so I turned off the 2008 server yesterday.  Everything worked fine for a few hrs, then network drives started breaking and a couple of apps broke that must somehow be pointed to the 2008 server for DNS.  I initially ignored a WINS migration because I thought that was more or less a legacy service for older versions of Windows.  I'm kind of scratching my head on this, any help is appreciated.

*edit*  I've since turned the old DC on to keep things from breaking.

Comment: Did you update all of the domain clients to use the new DC for DNS? Aside from that, it could literally be anything. Look at the event logs, run DCDIAG, run the relevant BPA's, etc., etc.

Comment: If you have shortcuts or printers with the previous server name, it may be possible to create a DNS CNAME for the previous server that points to the new server.

Comment: Although WINS is legacy, that doesn't necessarily mean you're not unknowingly depending on it if your DNS isn't comprehensive.  Typically I think it would be preferable to identify and correct any problems with the DNS than to just keep using WINS, but I suppose it depends on the scenario.

Comment: Assuming the IP address of the new DC is different than the IP of the old DC, you need to make sure all your clients have obtained the new IP address for the DNS server. DHCP should be updated to hand out the new DNS IP address. Make sure you haven’t mistakingly set the clients to use your modem or ISP for DNS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have your answer already:

> Everything worked fine for a few hrs, then network drives started breaking and a couple of apps broke that must somehow be pointed to the 2008 server for DNS.

Are you running DNS on the new server, and are your clients pointing to it?

Did you forget to authorize the new DHCP server?  Update the DHCP server with the new IP address of the new server for DNS?